# cannot find symbol...?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, dna-sequence, cannot-find-symbol

I have to write code that takes in a string of 3 letters and converts it to give the complement DNA (A==T, C==G AND REVERSE) string.

Although I think the code is okay, it keeps giving me the same error

> "cannot find symbol"

At the string dna (main method), as well as twice in the method header of the watsonCrickTripletCompliment. Would anyone know where I am going wrong

```
public class DnaUtilities {      
  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    string dna = "AGT"; //cannot find symbol         
    System.out.println (watsonCrickTripletComplement(dna));
  }

  public static string watsonCrickTripletComplement (string dna) { /*cannot find symbol at both string*/
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();     
    if (dna.length() > 3 || dna.length() < 3 )
      return "";        
     else {
       for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        char c = dna.charAt(i);
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'T'){
            builder.append('A');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'A'){
            builder.append('T');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'C'){
            builder.append('G');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
            builder.append('T');
        }   
    return builder.toString();        
       }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am assuming this is Java, since you do not say what the language is.
2. The word "string" is in **lowsercase**. You need to spell it **String**.

Comment: thankyou very much!! much appreciated :)

Comment: Would you mind accepting and +1 ing my answer :)

Comment: i just accepting, unfortunately i don't have 15 reputations so the +1 doesnt go public, so sorry

Comment: No problems! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass that non static string to a static function.   mark the string as static and it'll work.

Comment: i assumed c++ cause s was lowercase.  i cant comment yet so i do my best with guessing from context.

Comment: it was java!  thankyou so much anyway :)

Comment: Well, you should delete this answer, because it is completely wrong. This can happen due to the misinterpretation of the used language, but it won't help anybody.